# Calling CMake Makefile with another Makefile

Tags: makefile, cmake

I am attempting to call the auto-generated CMake makefile from outside of the CMake directory using make.

In order to accomplish this, I have made another makefile in the parent directory of my project. This file should cd into the CMake directory and call the makefile contained in there.

Unfortunately, I am having issues with the external makefile. The contents are as follows:

```
clean:
    cd cmake-build-debug && $(MAKE) clean
```

I have a tab following the final line, but am still getting a separation error.

Comment: What do you mean by "a separation error"?  Can you post a complete (but *minimal*) example, and the corresponding error message?

Comment: You state "I have a tab following the final line" -- the line `cd cmake-build...` should *begin* with a `tab` character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the `make` man-page:

```
-C dir, --directory=dir
        Change to directory dir before reading the makefiles or doing 
        anything  else.   If multiple  -C  options  are specified, 
        each is interpreted relative to the previous one: 
        -C / -C etc is equivalent to -C /etc.  This is typically 
        used with  recursive invocations of make.
```

So, your clean rule can be:

```
clean:
        $(MAKE) -C cmake-build-debug clean
```

Comment: While what you say is certainly correct it doesn't explain why `cd cmake-build-debug && $(MAKE) clean` *doesn't* work.

Comment: On second look it should work. I guess we'll see if  @MillerR updates the question to exactly what the problem/error message is.

Comment: Changing the makefile to this style was successful - I haven't a clue why.